# Sharepoint Site doesn't open on Safari 8.0.2

Tags: sharepoint-designer, browsers

I upgrated my software and Safari 8.0 installed with the update. My sharepoint site can open in Safari 8.0.
But I upgrated Safari 8.0 to Safari 8.0.2. But my sharepoint site can't open.

I searched this issue on the net. The problem stems from the windows authentication.

Should I need to make an amendment to the SharePoint side? Have you any information the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix:** Download Chrome from App Store and use it on your SharePoint site.

**Slow fix:** Change your Form Based Authentication (FBA) to Claims authentication in SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for answer Banny. How to I change authentication type on SharePoint 2013?

Comment: @zengel It's a complex process, but doable. Start reading here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Does this change disrupts existing identity or have it any side effects?